# Cast BindingSource Current into DataRow

Tags: c#

I need to capture the value of a specific field in the CurrentChange event. The problem is, I'm not sure how to convert a bindingSource.current (which returns an object) to a DataTable or equivalent so I can grab a field value.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: What is the DataSource for your BindingSource? A DataTable?

Comment: It's a DataSet, and the DisplayMember is the DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data source of your `BindingSource` is a `DataTable`, then the `Current` property will return an instance of [`DataRowView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.aspx). You can access the original `DataRow` through the `Row` property.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem and to show an example how it works:

```
 DataRowView row = (DataRowView)gttBindingSourceMain.Current;
        if (row != null)
        {
            string stringname = row["TheStringColumnName"].ToString();
            int intname = int.Parse(row["TheIntColumnName"].ToString());
        }
```